# Emails marked as spam in gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, spam-prevention, email-spam

I am recieving mails sent to here in spam folder .I  have shifted our email services to google mail.And this started happening since.

```
<?php
$message = "Our New app";
        $to='myname@adapty.com';
        $subject="New Mail";
        $from = 'noreply@adapty.com';
        $body='Just wanted to ask one thing as we are planning for release date, how long do you think it will take to test the android app?';
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
?>
```

I changed the from addres from noreply@adapty.com to myname@adapty.com still it was marked as spam.

Here is my [phpinfo](http://103.231.209.162:60070/phpinfo.php) .Please help.Thanks

Comment: use phpmailer or swiftmailer with some SMTP setting

Answer (score 0):

Try confirming the domain you're sending from has a valid SPF record for the website you're sending from.

Comment: How can i do this? I am using a control s server

Comment: You can use http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html to test if you have a SPF record, and http://www.spfwizard.net/ to generate one if you don't. This article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) contains a lot of useful information for understanding SPF records. But the tl;dr of it is, it allows email providers to check that certain domains are allowed to send email on behalf of other domains

Answer (score 0):

I found out one article **"[How do I stop my emails from being labeled as spam?](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/fighting-spam/stop-emails-being-labeled-spam)
"**.

On this article many thinks are cover like **Email Authentication - SPF and DomainKeys etc.**

The Article like:

"You may find yourself often fighting the frustration of having your business emails getting classified as spam in your customer email boxes. The fact is that about 80-90% of All email on the internet is spam. In spite of this, businesses anticipate increasing the number of email campaigns on the web.

To stop the bombardment, people and businesses are creating [filters](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-email/user-account-level-filtering), or buying company services that filter email so that they receive only content that they deem relevant to them. So, whether or not your email is legitimate, if a receiving host or email spam program is aggressive or set a certain way, your emails could very easily get marked as spam. Unfortunately, this is not a server or hosting issue. This is a general issue with email that you will find no matter where you host your business emails. This article discusses what you can do from your end.

Steps to take when your emails are flagged as spam

There are several things that may help, but bear mind these are suggestions and not a guarantee that your email will no longer be filtered as spam:

1. Make sure that you are not in violation of the [CAN-SPAM Act of 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN-SPAM_Act_of_2003). Verify that your emails make the grade and you're not falling into common filtering rules.
2. Send your customers a personal email message requesting that they white-list your domain, so that your business emails don't get filtered into Spam. In this, I'm referring to a "personal" email as one that doesn't include your marketing links or business advertisements or enhancements that may flag the email as something other than a personal email.
3. Check to make sure that your Email Authentication is enabled. This helps stop spam coming from your email address (even if you're not sending any that you know of). One of the common tactics by spammers out there is to spoof email coming from your domain. This causes you to get blacklisted even though you're not sending emails. Here's an article on these settings: [Email Authentication - SPF and DomainKeys.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/fighting-spam/email-authentication-spf-domainkeys)
4. If all else fails, you might want to consider a paid service or use a large specific email host for sending business emails- like Google mail. There are services for sending out emails for marketing such as [MailChimp.com](http://mailchimp.com/). Check them out as possible solutions since they can provide business email and newsletter services.
5. Examine your email bounces. When an email bounces, it will tell you "why" it's being bounced and give you a source or reason for the bounce. If you're being listed on a service (that you may not be aware of), then you should investigate. In some cases, you can very easily remove yourself from a list simply contacting the authority who has blacklisted you. This may not always be the same person as the email administrator of that server. However, you can also send an email to an email administrator of the service to find out why your emails are being blocked. Though, I would only do this after examining the reason for the block and ,making sure that you have done your due diligence by reading their bounce messages and confirmed that you're not sending spam.

Ultimately, you cannot force people to receive your emails or control how they perceive when an email is being labeled as spam or junk email. You can only control those factors that may lead your domain or email as being labeled as a spam by observing the reaction to the emails that you send out. Hopefully, the information that I have provided will help you (and anyone else reading this post) in at least stopping spam being inadvertently being sent as well as providing possible solutions that will lead to successfully marketing your business through email."